# Is this model nonlinear?

Tags: state-space

I have this state-space model:

[image: State Space]

Is this state space model nonlinear? If it is, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [linear differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) . It stems from the following electric circuit :

[image]

Were the resistor `R`, the capacitor `C` and the inductor `L` are ideal [linear components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_element). `x1` is the current from the generator of voltage `d.u1` and `x2` is the voltage of the resistor-capacitor.

To check linearity, let `u1_1(t)` and `u1_2(t)` be two input signals. The corresponding output signals are `x1_1(t),x2_1(t)` and `x1_2(t),x2_2(t)`. Then it is easy to see that the output signal corresponding to `u1_1(t)+u1_2(t)` is `x1_1(t)+x1_2(t),x2_1(t)+x2_2(t)`.

The Laplace transform and the Fourier transform can be used to study this system and compute output signals whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, that makes sense. The circuit that I'm considering is a synchronous buck converter, so yes, that corresponds at one mode of conduction. Now imagine that u1 and d are in fact d(t) and u1(t). This would make this model non-linear?

Comment: If `d` and `u1` are both considered as inputs, the model is non-linear. Think about `(d(t),0)` and `(0,u1(t))` as sets of inputs. In both cases, the output is 0. But the output corresponding to `(d(t)+0,0+u1(t))` is not necessarily 0 ! However, if both `d` and `u1` are known, `d.u1` can be computed and used as input of the linear part. Hence, the analysis of the linear part is not useless.

Comment: One final question: Imagine that my resistor, R, is variable in time. So I could say that it is another state, like x3, right?. Is this possible to represent in another state space model?

Comment: If the function R(t) is kown, then the problem is still linear since the demonstration using `u1_1` and `u1_2` holds true. If R(t) is a new variable like x1 or x2, then the problem is not linear anymore.

Comment: Right. My question was more like if R now is equal to x3(t), so the last term would become x2(t)/(C*x3(t)). Is this poossible? I never saw anything like this (with a state dividing by other state) and I was thinking how this could be represented.

Comment: if R is equal to `x3(t)` where `x3(t)` is a variable, then the problem is not linear anymore...and i can't see how variables could be defined to turn the problem into something linear. Notice that an extra equation is needed if you want the problem to have a unique solution. If this equation happens to be easy to solve, then you are back to a linear system !